# How to continue in a loop when the file does not exist?

Tags: matlab

This script download many files. However, I want the loop to continue when it doesn't find any file: File mot found.

```
for ii=1:length(t2)
   d=t2(ii);
   if year(d)>=2011
       download(d)

 end
end
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `download` is a function that downloads something from a server, so I don't see how `exist` will work. Either way, you can simply use a `try` `catch` block:

```
for ii=1:length(t2)
    d=t2(ii);
    if year(d)>=2011
        try
            download(d)
        catch
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an 'if' statement before the `download(d)` statement to ask whether the file exists.  Something like:

```
for ii=1:length(t2)
   d=t2(ii);
   if year(d)>=2011
       if exist(d)   % where d is the file
          download(d)
       else
          continue  % Jump to next loop iteration if file doesn't exist
       end
   end
end
```

Assuming that 'd' is the file in question that you want to download.  You might need to use the file's whole address to make sure Matlab can find it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the check before downloading you can do `try-catch`. This `download` is likely to throw an error if file is missing or something (`load` does, but I don't have `download`). You get this error for `load`:

Error using load
Unable to read file 'lala.m'. No such file or directory.

Now the same with `try-catch`:

```
try
   load('lala.m')
catch
   disp('No such file')
end
```

It will display `No such file`, which might not be the real error thrown by `load`, but you can do multiple catches.

This doesn't have a large advantage when the only thing that can go wrong is "file does not exist", but if you have multiple possible fail points you can have single `try-catch` (if you don't care what went wrong, just that something did) instead of a long cascade of `ifs` checking everything.